# How to place implicit objects in a package?

Tags: scala

I'm trying to put some implicit converters in a package so that when I:

```
import packagename._
```

it imports implicit objects as well.

Currently, I just use an object instead of a package:

```
object Quote {
  case class Quote(symbol: String, price: Int, time: Date)
  implicit val format = Json.format [Quote]
}
```

But, that just feels wrong e.g. I can't split an object definition on multiple files.

I want to do this:

```
package Quote

case class Quote(symbol: String, price: Int, time: Date)
implicit val format = Json.format [Quote] // this isn't allowed
```

But, that's not allowed.

What's the standard way of defining implicit objects in Scala **in a package** so that when the package is imported with "._" the calling code imports the implicits too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use package object:

```
package object packagename {
  case class Quote(symbol: String, price: Int, time: Date)
  implicit val format = Json.format [Quote]
}
```

Comment: Where should you place the imports? inside the package object or at the top just after the "package xxx" line?

Comment: In Scala in general you can place imports (almost) anywhere you want. They are valid for the block in which you put them. But put them at the top if you have no reason to reduce their scope.